# Bitwise expression for 1 and 4

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

so I need an bitwise expression which will output 1
for the input 1 , and 8 for the input 4
Input: 1 > Output:1
Input:4 > Output:8
The expression should be 5-6 chars long. 
arithmetics operations are allowed

Thank you :)

Comment: "*The expression should be 5-6 chars long*" - is this homework?

Comment: no , but i know the length of it.

Answer (score 0):

Homework?

Assuming `unsigned char a;`

```
a << (a >> 2)
```

If arithmetic operations are allowed it can be a bit shorter:

```
a << a/4
```